# Polyglossia: Arabic Text, English Bibliography

Tags: bibtex, polyglossia, right-to-left

I am writing a mainly Arabic book. But all the references are western/English. So I'd like the bibliography to appear left to right. I write:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{book}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Arabic Typesetting}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{arabic}
تجربة
\selectlanguage{english}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{MyRef}
\end{document}
```

and after compiling with XeTeX and BibTeX, I get: `Undefined control sequence \begin{thebibliography}{10}`
But if I remove the  `\selectlanguage{english}` command, then it works fine, but references are now right to left.

EDIT: the (left to right) bibliography do appear correctly, although this need lots of iterations, deleting .aux files, deleting .bbl file, re-compiling, etc. But the error is always there and I believe there is something wrong.

Comment: That's a bug in polyglossia. It "undefines" `\MakeUppercase`. Add `\makeatletter\let\orig@MakeUppercase \MakeUppercase\makeatother` to your preamble before loading the arabic files.