# Arabic bibliography in English document: Disconnected letters

Tags: biblatex, xetex, arabic, right-to-left

I'm writing in English about Arabic collocations, quoting both English and Arabic sources. As there are many sources, I use a sectioned bibliography, filtering for keywords with biblatex, where each sections consists of either only English or only Arabic sources.

Using XeTeX and polyglossia, the main language of my document is English, so I have to switch to Arabic for the Arabic sections of my bibliography. This works partially insofar as the section is right-to-left, but the Arabic letters are disconnected.

## Garbled output

[image: Disconnected letters]

## Minimal (not) working example

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Amiri}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs_test.bib}
@Article{Ghazala1993,
  author       = {غزالة, حسن},
  title        = {ترجمة المتلازمات اللفظية (عربي-انجليزي)},
  journaltitle = {ترجمان},
  year         = {1993},
  keywords     = {arabic},
}
@Book{Baalbaki1987,
  author    = {Baalbaki, Munir},
  title     = {Al-Mawrid: A Modern Arabic-English Dictionary},
  year      = {1987},
  publisher = {Dar al-'Ilm li'l-Malayin},
  address   = {Beirut},
  keywords  = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{refs_test.bib}

\usepackage{xunicode}

\begin{document}

Sample enumeration:
\begin{enumerate}
\item first
\item second
\end{enumerate}

\section{References}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[keyword={english}, title={English Dictionaries}, heading=subbibliography]
\selectlanguage{arabic}
\printbibliography[keyword={arabic}, title={قواميس عربية}, heading=subbibliography]

\end{document}
```

*NB:* I am aware of the following questions, which deal with related but different problems:

- [Arabic bibliography with biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/arabic-bibliography-with-biblatex) is concerned with adding Arabic sources to a (mostly) English bibliography
- [Polyglossia: Arabic Text, English Bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/176661/polyglossia-arabic-text-english-bibliography) is the inverse situation: Arabic document, English bibliography.

## Edit: Adding `Script=Arabic` as suggested by Salim Bou

Using

```
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
```

makes the letter get connected, but seems to turn the document from LTR to RT: In enumerations, for example, the numbers are preceded by points, not the other way around. (*To make this point clear, I added an enumeration to the MWE and updated the images.*)

[image]

Comment: Just change `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Amiri}` to  `\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}` same for `\setsansfont`

Comment: @SalimBou: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it out, but it seems to make the whole document RTL - I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: What about surrounding your Arabic text in the `bib` file and document with `\textarabic{}`? e.g., `author = {\textarabic{غزال, حسن}}` You might also have to create an arabic `csquotes` style to get the quotation marks right. And you will probably need various `sort` fields to make sure your bibliography (and index) is sorted correctly.

Comment: @DavidPurton: That's the approch suggested in [Arabic bibliography with biblatex](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/106718/arabic-bibliography-with-biblatex). But it's a very hacky way to add formatting markup to `bib` file ... especially since biblatex is able to produce a somewhat correct bibliography without this markup when the document's main language is Arabic. (Only somewhat: As you mentioned, quotation marks are wrong and some strings, like "In" for articles, need to be translated.)

Comment: As suggested by Salim Bou, change your main font... but locally: `{\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Script=Arabic]{Amiri} \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}\selectlanguage{arabic}\printbibliography[keyword={arabic}, title={قواميس عربية}, heading=subbibliography]}`

Comment: @PaulGaborit Thanks, that did it! Would you mind posting this comment as an answer so that I can accept it? (I would appreciate if you could share your thoughts on localizing the bibliography strings: The approach to replace English strings with Arabic suggested in [How to do a proper Bibliography in Arabic language with XeLaTeX and Biblatex-Biber backend?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172541/how-to-do-a-proper-bibliography-in-arabic-language-with-xelatex-and-biblatex-bib?lq=1) doesn't work here because I have both English and Arabic ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by Salim Bou, change your main font... but locally using `{...}`:

```
{
   \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
   \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
   \selectla‌​nguage{arabic}
   \print‌​bibliography[keyword‌​={arabic}, title={قواميس عربية}, heading=subbibliography]
}
```

[image]

Whole document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Amiri}
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Amiri}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Ghazala1993,
  author       = {غزالة, حسن},
  title        = {ترجمة المتلازمات اللفظية (عربي-انجليزي)},
  journaltitle = {ترجمان},
  year         = {1993},
  keywords     = {arabic},
}
@Book{Baalbaki1987,
  author    = {Baalbaki, Munir},
  title     = {Al-Mawrid: A Modern Arabic-English Dictionary},
  year      = {1987},
  publisher = {Dar al-'Ilm li'l-Malayin},
  address   = {Beirut},
  keywords  = {english}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xunicode}

\begin{document}

Sample enumeration:
\begin{enumerate}
\item first
\item second
\end{enumerate}

\section{References}

\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[keyword={english}, title={English Dictionaries}, heading=subbibliography]

{
  \setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
  \setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text,Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
  \selectlanguage{arabic}
  \printbibliography[keyword={arabic}, title={قواميس عربية}, heading=subbibliography]
}
\end{document}
```